# Using partitionId or partitionKey with Iot Hub Azure

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

We are developing an application where IoT devices will be publishing events to azure IoT hub using MQTT protocol (by using one topic to push message). We want to consume these message using Stream Analytic service. And to scale Stream analytic services, it is recommended to use partitionBy clause.

Since, we are not using Azure Event hub SDK, can we somehow attached partitionId with events?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: What will be the output of your Stream Analytic job?

Comment: It will store the result into some database.

Comment: Then don't bother. Using `partition By` only has effect when the destination also supports partitioning, like another Event Hub.

Comment: But I would not able to use PartitionBy in query and without it maximum 6 units can be utilized.

Comment: "without it maximum 6 units can be utilized" -> That is not true, it depends on the target destination if it can handle the load. But again, if your target does not support partitioning there is no use of the `partition by` keyword. See also the link in my accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46129842/does-azure-stream-analytics-read-data-coming-from-all-partitions/46130414#46130414). `partition by` is only useful if you can connect a source partition to a target partition. Since databases don't support this mechanism you cannot use it.

Comment: Please have a look at this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-scale-jobs . As per this, you cannot use more than 6 units, if partitions are not utilized. Other than that, how can I run stream analytics in parallel. I mean if one stream analytics engine is working on one set of events, other instance can start picking other sets of events?

Comment: IoT Hub does not allow arbitrary partitioning. [Device-to-cloud messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-d2c#route-device-to-cloud-messages) are partitioned based on their originating deviceId.

Answer (score 0):

As Rita mentioned in the comments, Event Hub will automatically associate each device to a particular partition.

Then, when you can use PARTITION BY PartitionId for steps closer to the input to efficiently parallelize processing of the input and reduce/aggregate the data.
Then, you can have another non-partitioned step to output to SQL sending some aggregate data.

Doing that you will be able to assign more thank 6 SUs, even with an output to SQL.

We will update our documentation to give more info about scaling ASA jobs and describe the different possible scenarios.

Thanks,

JS - Azure Stream Analytics